What are the cons and pros of giving a name to each of the 12 notes rather than having sharps and flats?
I've been messing aroung the keyboard, the musical software, the notation and came to a conclusion that if we had names for all 12 notes then reading music and writing music would be much easier. Since we wouldn't need to spend time on understanding sharps and flats and we could have an easier diagram for note writing, not 7 notes and then pitching them using a # or a b sign.
But the only problem I find now is that we would need to adapt all the sheet music currently in existence.
What do you think?

Why would sheet music need to be changed? The usual notation doesn't have note names anywhere.

Because there would be now 12 notes instead of 7

This is a good in depth discussion on this subject.

@SovereignSun there are already more than 12 notes. And even if you believe that there are 7 notes, there are still only 5 lines on the staff.

You're talking about a choice of written and spoken language, and how well a particular language would serve different cultures and practical situations.
The seven-notes-per-octave system is a good fit for the kind of musical culture where pieces tend to use at most seven distinct notes per octave at any one time, and where harmony is reasoned about using an assumed seven-note context. In that kind of thinking and culture, a seven-note context is defined by a key signature, and if an accidental is needed, it can be seen as a change to the context. If there are no accidentals, you can assume that the harmonic context probably stays the same.
Harmonic contexts often also include a center pitch or "home note", and even though the center pitch isn't strictly defined by a key signature, due to the prevailing musical culture, one can make educated guesses based on the key signature. A twelve-note system would not provide such contextual hints.
Having seven, rather than 12 notes per octave also makes the notation more condensed, for music that's made in the culture that tends to have seven-note harmonic contexts. A wider pitch range fits on the stave vertically.
Could a twelve-note-name system possibly have benefits in any case? There are some styles of music that use chromaticism and enharmonic re-interpretations a lot, and a 12-note system could be more true to such music's nature. Or if the music uses more than seven notes per octave, like diminished scales. For those kinds of music, the seven note name language is not an ideal fit, because it forces one to select one enharmonic spelling for each pitch, even if the whole idea is to make the enharmonic spelling ambiguous.
Musical pieces in guitar rock and metal genres sometimes come from fretboard based thinking, and in those cases a 12-note system could be a reasonable fit. Metal guitar players often think in terms of fret numbers rather than traditional note names. But even then, I assume they'd rather take numbers than any letter names.

Metal guitar players often think in terms of boxes that are shapes different scales take on fretboard. So it's still far away from pure dodecaphony.

This is somewhat of a subjective question, but the answer is partly in what you surmise. Hundreds of years of written music would not conform. That alone is a good enough reason!
That apart, how many lines/spaces would be needed? Many more, I feel, and that in itself would be problematic in that for a lot of us, ten lines, split by a wide space, is quite enough! And - what would all the notes then be known as?
It could, of course, be beneficial to certain instruments, but right now, I can't think of one. For piano, starters, having black keys as ♯/♭ (nominally) it would be a hindrance more than a help.
The sharps/flats debate will go on for ever, (while they still exist...) but that system has and does work for the majority of musos. If it ain't broke...

I think you are too conservative. Why only 12 notes? There are alternative tone systems with 24 notes (quarter tone). Most of us westerners today are used to the equal-tempered tone system, but there are alternatives. Traditional blues as example does have a few "false" notes, some Chinese and Arabic music has other "false" notes to an ear used to equal temperament. Not to talk about music written before the invention of equal temperament when played historically correct.
I believe the reason why we use the note names and notation is because they simply work. Historically several different systems has been in use and tried but the current system has prevailed. It is reasonably easy to read, write and talk about. If you want to design a different system, it needs to be shown to be useable. So start out making that demonstration and come back when it is in place.
